# Defining and using fixed array type

Tags: typescript

I have the following map:

`var myMap = new Map<string, [string, number]>()`

The values of this map are always going to be a 2-item array, the first item being a string, and the second item being a number

`myMap.set("foo", ["bar", 42])`

This works as expected. Additionally, have an array with extra members does not work, also as expected

`myMap.set("foo", ["bar", 42, 0]) // too many arguments`

The problem I'm having is defining this outside of the `set()`:

```
var value = ["bar", 42]
myMap.set("foo", value)
```

This causes the following error:

```
Argument of type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, number]'.
  Type '(string | number)[]' is missing the following properties from type '[string, number]': 0, 1
```

I can fix this by forcing the type:

`var value = <[string, number]>["bar", 42]`

But I hate doing this as it seems too verbose (I very well may have arrays that are defined as 10 or 15 members). Is there anything else I can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are defining these tuples statically (e. g. by writing them by hand in source code) and you're able to define the values as `readonly`, then you can use the `as const` type assertion to ensure TypeScript infers the tuple type rather than the array type:

```
var myMap = new Map<string, readonly [string, number]>()
const value = ['hello', 123] as const;
myMap.set("foo", value); // Works as expected
```

Comment: hrm, interesting. Good to know! Although I don't know yet if my usecase would allow for that - I'll be looking over a collection, and the tuple is actually going to be composed of items in that collection. But I'll definitely give it a shot :)

Comment: Just did a quick check, and so far this is exactly what I'm looking for. Recently release feature too, which might explain why i couldn't find a lot of resources for it. Thanks! For more information, I found this article helpful: https://blog.logrocket.com/const-assertions-are-the-killer-new-typescript-feature-b73451f35802/

Answer (score 1):

With a little helper we can define a type alias for the value type of the map which can be used instead:

```js
type MapValue<M extends Map<any, any>> = M extends Map<any, infer V> ? V : never;

var myMap = new Map<string, [string, number]>()
var value: MapValue<typeof myMap> = ["bar", 42] // value: [string, number]
myMap.set("foo", value)
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmAanANgVwgHhlCAPYCAOwBMBnWBTOIkAGihpAD5moBeWXA48ysarQYBLIgDMIAJyiI2AfhlQAXFCIQAblIDcAKB3q40gLYh4YDqogB3fpjLBJogOYMA2vcdEXqtEYBGUgC6zAAUAJT6hlAG6BAqZsixmKCQAPZiUCZmbJyuAER+hnkMACwATIE6WQgAdGQQwCF5YqmpxdGoGGFAA)

Comment: Isn't that quite similar to forcing the Type on value Like blitzmann suggested in the end of his question?

Comment: @Steven yes but they mention "I very well may have arrays that are defined as 10 or 15 members" so I understood the "too verbose" to refer writing the individual types of the tuple members.

Comment: Well, both are correct. This helps specifically the verbosity of having many members, however I'm still interested if there is a way to infer the value without having to declare it (I assume not).

I think I could also define `type val = [string, number]` then `var myMap = new Map<string, val>(); value = <val>["bar", 42]` which also seems to work and also helps with the situations in which I might have many different members